# Split table in two tables plus a link table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with three columns with double values, but no double rows. Now I want to split this table in two table with unique values and a link table. I think the Problem gets clearer when I Show you example tables:

```
Original:
| ID | Column_1 | Column_2 | Column_3 |
|----|----------|----------|----------|
| 1  | A        | 123      | A1       |
| 2  | A        | 123      | A2       |
| 3  | B        | 234      | A2       |
| 4  | C        | 456      | A1       |

Table_1
| ID | Column_1 | Column_2 |
|----|----------|----------|
| 1  | A        | 123      |
| 2  | B        | 234      |
| 3  | C        | 456      |

Table_2
| ID | Column_3 |
|----|----------|
| 1  | A1       |
| 2  | A2       |

Link-Table
| ID | fk1 | fk2 |
|----|-----|-----|
| 1  | 1   | 1   |
| 2  | 1   | 2   |
| 3  | 2   | 2   |
| 4  | 3   | 1   |
```

Table_1 I created like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table_1(Column_1, Column_2) 
SELECT DISTINCT Column_1, Column_2 FROM Original
WHERE Original.Column_1 NOT IN (SELECT Column_1 FROM Table_1)
```

Table_2 I created in the same way.

The question now is, how to create the Link-Table?
The original table does grow continuesly, so only new entries should be added.
Do I have to use a Cursor, or is there a better way?

SOLUTION:

```
MERGE Link_Table AS LT
USING (SELECT DISTINCT T1.ID AS T1ID, T2.ID AS T2ID FROM Original AS O
                     INNER JOIN Table_1 AS T1 ON T1.Column_1 = O.Column_1
                     INNER JOIN Table_2 AS T2 ON T2.Column_3 = O.Column_3) AS U
ON LT.fk1 = U.T1ID
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (fk1, fk2)
VALUES (U.T1ID, U.T2ID);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can JOIN all 3 tables to get proper data for link table:

```
--INSERT INTO [Link-Table]
SELECT  t1.ID,
        t2.ID
FROM Original o
INNER JOIN Table_1 t1
    ON t1.Column_1 = o.Column_1 
INNER JOIN Table_2 t2
    ON t2.Column_3 = o.Column_3
```

If your original table will grow, then you need to use MERGE to update/insert new data.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I solved it. See my original post for solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to inner join your Original,Table_1 and Table_2 to get the desired result.

Try like this, Its similar to gofr1 post.

```
DECLARE @orginal TABLE (
    ID INT
    ,Column_1 VARCHAR(10)
    ,Column_2 INT
    ,Column_3 VARCHAR(10)
    )
DECLARE @Table_1 TABLE (
    ID INT
    ,Column_1 VARCHAR(10)
    ,Column_2 INT
    )
DECLARE @Table_2 TABLE (
    ID INT
    ,Column_3 VARCHAR(10)
    )

Insert into @orginal values 
(1,'A',123,'A1')
,(2,'A',123,'A2')
,(3,'B',234,'A2')
,(4,'C',456,'A1')

Insert into @Table_1 values
(1,'A',123)
,(2,'B',234)
,(3,'C',456)

Insert into @Table_2 values
(1,'A1')
,(2,'A2')

SELECT O.ID
    ,T1.ID
    ,T2.ID
FROM @orginal O
INNER JOIN @Table_1 T1 ON T1.Column_1 = O.Column_1
INNER JOIN @Table_2 T2 ON T2.Column_3 = O.Column_3
```